# get the dates of specific day of week

Tags: java, android

How to be able to know the date of a specific day in next month in java

for example if I enter Friday I need the output to be as following

Friday 9 Jun 2017
Friday 16 Jun 2017
Friday 23 Jun 2017
Friday 30 Jun 2017

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, but I could not find a specifically Android related version of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JUNE , 9 )
     .with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) )
```

You can use java.time.LocalDate and java.time.TemporalAdjusters

[java.time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

For Android library to do this code, use the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project, an adaptation of the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. See [How to use ThreeTenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).